# League of legends, new client

Tags: games

I tried to install a new alpha League of Legends client using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Unfortunately, something went wrong and the game has crashed every time I've tried to run it.

How can I install a new client correctly?

Comment: in order to help you, much more information is needed. I guess you installed the Client using Wine, am i right? Than please point this out. 

Also if you have any errorlogs or something - whatever it is, it helps a lot in answering the question. Anything. What have you done so far? in what emulation mode did you try running it? etc.

Have you read the tutorials on wineHQ already? https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303

Comment: I installed lol by using "Play on Linux". The used  wine version  to run Lol is 1.9.2.  After update, game has crashed everytime i tried to run it without any error. Then i lunched the game in debug mode.  I got the log file: http://textuploader.com/d57yr
Thats all.  Do u need someting else? BTW. Thanks for help ;0

Comment: "Then i lunched the game in debug mode. " - did it taste well? ;D (sorry, couldn't resist..) 

i guess you have tried reinstalling it already? if not, try it.

Comment: I meant "launched" :P. I did but it does not work still. I added all libraries and still nothing.  Dont know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to the log you have to do the following: "I am assuming you are using play on linux"

- [Select Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY13G.png)
- Select Configure Wine
- Select Librairies
- You seem to be missing [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9g2a.png)

You might need to add some other overrides so check your log and add accordingly.